# What's the difference between travis-ci.org and travis-ci.com?

Tags: travis-ci

A few of the GitHub projects I contribute to use Travis CI for build testing. However, I've noticed that some projects use  [travis-ci.org](https://travis-ci.org/) for build testing, while others use [travis-ci.com](https://travis-ci.com/). Both sites seem to function identically, even down to using the same UI.

**What's the difference between [travis-ci.org](https://travis-ci.org/) and [travis-ci.com](https://travis-ci.com/)? Why do some projects use one over the other?**

Answer (score 82):

Travis CI originally created two separated platforms to differentiate between private repos / paid ([travis-ci.com](https://travis-ci.com)) and public repos / free ([travis-ci.org](https://travis-ci.org)).

However, as of May 2018, new users and projects (both private and public) should only use travis-ci.com (see [this blog post](https://blog.travis-ci.com/2018-05-02-open-source-projects-on-travis-ci-com-with-github-apps)). Note that **travis-ci.org will be closed down completely on December 31st, 2020** (see [this newsletter](https://mailchi.mp/3d439eeb1098/travis-ciorg-is-moving-to-travis-cicom)).

Although still in beta—which is a bit weird since travis-ci.org will be shut down soon—Travis CI provides a well-documented [migration guide](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/migrate/open-source-repository-migration).

Comment: Some (?) repos appear to still be on the .org e.g. https://travis-ci.org/citation-style-language/styles. So this migration is ongoing/slow.

Comment: @hayd yep, that's true. Updated the answer with a link to the migration guide.

Comment: According to the migration guide, migration from travis-ci.org to travis-ci.com is still in [closed beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#Open_and_closed_beta).

Comment: I (Sept. 2019) just learned of this. I have many repos on .org. I had to trigger migration manually (as in the linked migration doc) so I gather that migration will not be automatic.

Comment: @josephwb thx, I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Travis CI [changed it's pricing model](https://blog.travis-ci.com/2020-11-02-travis-ci-new-billing) ahead of the shutdown. Public projects are now limited to a trial plan. (See [1](https://blog.travis-ci.com/2020-11-02-travis-ci-new-billing), [2](https://travis-ci.community/t/org-com-migration-unexpectedly-comes-with-a-plan-change-for-oss-what-exactly-is-the-new-deal/10567), [3](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2020/travis-cis-new-pricing-plan-threw-wrench-my-open-source-works), [4](https://devclass.com/2020/11/25/travis-ci-open-source-engagement/))

Comment: We're halfway through January and travis-ci-org is still processing builds, and the migration to .com is still "in beta".  On the bright side, with so many people having already migrated, builds process quickly on whatever's left on .org...

Comment: Builds on travis-ci.org stopped on June 15, 2021 : https://blog.travis-ci.com/2021-05-07-orgshutdown

Answer (score 17):

[As of May 2018](https://blog.travis-ci.com/2018-05-02-open-source-projects-on-travis-ci-com-with-github-apps), travis-ci.org is scheduled to shut down and should no longer be used. Please refer to [beatngu13's answer](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/4305/2449) for updated information.

---

#### <s>Aside from pricing model, the two sites are identical.</s>

- [travis-ci.org](https://travis-ci.org/) is a free service for public open source projects.
- [travis-ci.com](https://travis-ci.com/) is a paid service for private commercial projects.

[From the FAQ page for Travis Pro](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/travis-pro/#Why-can%E2%80%99t-I-find-information-on-pricing-on-travis-ci.org%3F)

> #### Why can’t I find information on pricing on travis-ci.org?
>
> Travis CI is, and always will be, free for open source projects.
>
> For a list of plans and prices for private repositories, look at
> [travis-ci.com/plans](https://travis-ci.com/plans).

Comment: Not true anymore, travis-ci.com has also "free service for public open source projects" since I think 2018. This is also stated under travis-ci.com/plans.

Comment: @dr0i I noted at the start of my answer that the information was out of date. I've now crossed out the rest of the post to make this clearer.

Comment: @Steveoisiak just learned that there is the `1000 free minutes` restriction. Added an answer myself.

Answer (score 2):

There is one profound difference which is a bit hard to find:

Unfortunately the free OSS public repos at `travis-ci.com` are restricted to 1000 free build minutes after which one will have to beg for extra build minutes for the 'trial plan'.
[Travis CI announced this new pricing model at 2020-11-02](https://blog.travis-ci.com/2020-11-02-travis-ci-new-billing). Effectively this ends generous open source offering.

[Read Jeff Geerlin's comprehensive experience of migration to `travis-ci.com`](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2020/travis-cis-new-pricing-plan-threw-wrench-my-open-source-works).