# How to exit Migration purgatory on Travis CI for free/open source project?

Tags: travis-ci, migration

My apologies if the title does not make much sense. I'm not sure the name of the limbo I am in.

I contribute to several free/open source projects. For example, one of the projects is Wei Dai's [Crypto++](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp). My testing fork is on GitHub at [Noloader-Crypto++](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp).

Today three of my projects went missing, including Crypto++. Crypto++ looks like it has been reset. The entire build history is missing, and there's a hammer and nail animation when visiting the [Travis page](https://travis-ci.com/noloader/cryptopp). Whatever happened, it happened sometime today.

After poking around I found them moved to the Migrate area. I don't know what migrate is and how to achieve it. Migrate is greyed out so I probably can't migrate even if that is what I am supposed to do.

[image]

I'd like to move the repos back to the free/open source project area so I can run jobs again.

How do I get out of Migration purgatory? Or how do I move the repos back to the free/open source projects area so I can run jobs again?

This may (or may not) be related: [What's the difference between travis-ci.org and travis-ci.com?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/1201/9665). But I don't really understand what is going on or migration to connect the dots.

Comment: I see you've already posted in the [community forum](https://travis-ci.community/t/free-open-source-repos-went-missing/5631), might be worth syncing your account GitHub account with Travis CI again as sometimes authentication issues mean repositories seem to disappear.